# deleting null or __HIVE_DEFAULT_PARTITION__ in from hive external table and also from HDFS directory

Tags: hive, hiveql, external-tables, bigdata

i am trying to delete a **null**/**HIVE_DEFAULT_PARTITION** in from hive external table and also from HDFS directory but i couldn't delete it .. i have been to some other post regarding the same issue and i tried those even tho it is not showing any error the partition is not getting deleted.

**process_date=20160208

process_date=__HIVE_DEFAULT_PARTITION__**

these are the partitions in my table now. and i just want to delete the hive default partition.  (this is external table so i need to delete the same from HDFS too)

i tried this

**ALTER TABLE Table_Name DROP IF EXISTS PARTITION(process_date='__HIVE_DEFAULT_PARTITION__');**

i am getting below error

Error: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException Unexpected unknown partitions for (process_date = null) (state=42000,code=40000)

i tried the below

**ALTER TABLE table_name DROP PARTITION(process_date<'1');**

no error but hive default partition is still there.

Please help me with the problem.

Comment: You could try deleting the hdfs folder directly using hadoop fs -rm <> and then in hive use the msck repair table to refresh the metastore.

Comment: i agree it works that way but the problem is still if i want to automate that process what should i do ? real time when i run the ETL load and something fails and i need to remove the partition then what is the best way ?

Comment: in prod scenario. The default hive partition or NULL comes when your data has the partition value NULL , which i suppose is not desired.

Comment: some cases i am getting partiton value null even tho there is some partition exists. the problem happens because using data is loading to hive tables using ETL tool like informatica.. so if something happens then i am getting this problem.  for refreshing view i am taking the latest partition only. so in this case when i get hive default partition i cant refresh view because its pointing to the latest partition. i have to delete that....... and i checked the HDFS path now and hive default partition is not showing there.. the other partition i can see in HSFS path..

Comment: If you have null data as partition value , then the only way is to delete it from hdfs itself.Hive wont be able to recognize null partitions sometimes.

Comment: okie....if it was a managed table instead of external table will it be able to drop using alter table command ?

Comment: I guess your partition type is not string thus "ALTER TABLE Table_Name DROP IF EXISTS PARTITION(process_date='__HIVE_DEFAULT_PARTITION__')" did not work. If it would not be a problem for you, change your partition column type to string and try to run above drop statement.

Answer (score 3):

The way to do this is alter the type of the partition column to string,

Then this syntax will work:

```
ALTER TABLE Table_Name DROP IF EXISTS PARTITION(process_date='__HIVE_DEFAULT_PARTITION__')
```

Then alter the type of the partition column back to it's original.

Then 
See

[https://www.ericlin.me/2015/07/how-to-drop-hives-default-partition-**hive_default_partition**-with-int-partition-column/](https://www.ericlin.me/2015/07/how-to-drop-hives-default-partition-__hive_default_partition__-with-int-partition-column/)

Answer (score 0):

This answer is to help others who might be facing same/similar issue.

The below query should help when you face the error - **SemanticException Unexpected unknown partitions for (part_column = null)**

Use **'!='** (Not Equal to) and give supported value/values

```
ALTER TABLE <table_name> DROP IF EXISTS PARTITION(report_year!='2018');
```